# Why is passing stateful objects to constructor a bad thing?

Tags: php, oop, solid-principles

It is my intuitional understanding that instantiating objects by passing their constructors a stateful object is a bad practice. Take this code for example:

```
class MathValues
{
    private $x;

    public function __construct($x, $y)
    {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }

    public function getX()
    {
        return $this->x;
    }

    public function getY()
    {
        return $this->y;
    }
}

class MathCalculator
{
    private $mathValues;

    public function __construct(MathValues $class)
    {
        $this->mathValues = $class;
    }

    public function calculateMultiplication()
    {
        return $this->mathValues->getX() * $this->mathValues->getY();
    }
}

$mathValues = new MathValues(2,5);

$mathCalculator = new MathCalculator($mathValues);
$someValue = $mathCalculator->calculateMultiplication();
```

Now, I have been a web developer for a long time and only recently I've started developing in OOP paradigm, following(as hard as I can) SOLID principles, service oriented architecture, etc. Also for some time now I've been developing using Symfony2/3 framework. Everything I see out there(including Symfony's service container) says that constructor should be used to pass other services(stateless instances) but I can not for the life of me find what principle says that you should not pass a stateful object to a constructor.

So my question is as in the header - What principle says that it's a bad thing to pass a stateful object to a constructor?

**UPDATE**

It seems my question has not been clear enough, so I updated my example. In this example problems and the solution is clear: **every time, when I need to multiply something, I need to create 2 instances of 2 classes**. Instead, I could create a single service MathCalculator and pass it 2 arguments - x and y. So what I'd need is only 1 instance for all the values i want to do math operations to and an object for every value(if even needed) that i need to do math operation with.

**Not to mention** that stateful programming is a bad dynamic and I believe in separating value immutable objects and services that do not have state at all.

Comment: state exists after you [compose your object graphs with confidence](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/)

Comment: Why do you think it's a bad thing?

Comment: I think it'is not really related Symfony question.

Comment: Hm, i thought it would be appropriate, since I mention Symfony and most of my thoughts about this are based on working with it... But i removed it anyway

Comment: It's more that objects taken in the constructor should have the same lifetime as that class.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as you already recognise since you mentioned it in your update, it isn't ideal to keep instantiating new `MathCalculators` every time you have different `MathValues` for it to operate on.

The first thing you need to ask is whether values `x` and `y` actually have any domain-specific, real-life relationship to each other with regards to `MathCalculator`. If they can both be just random values that a user enters, then putting them both in the same class is not good - `S` of `SOLID` says you should apply the principle of single responsibility or encapsulation. One instance of `MathValues` should have one value and `y` should become another instance of `MathValues`, so in this case `MathValues` becomes redundant and you can just use a set or list of numbers.

I suspect you are using `MathValues` as a [Data Transfer Object (DTO)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)

Otherwise, if `x` and `y` are somehow related and they do belong in the same class, e.g. geodata or grid references, then what you have done with `MathValues` is an example of the [Anaemic Domain Model](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) anti-pattern and a violation of the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

You should put your business logic into your entity to adhere to the `S` of `SOLID` - the responsibility for knowing how to multiply x and y belongs to `MathValues`, so to satisfy the duty of single responsibility and encapsulation, you should refactor that method into that class.

Admittedly this is debatable because actually your `MathValues` also looks like a DDD [Value Object](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html) in which case you wouldn't want any logic in there, rather you would aggregate the `MathValues` into a aggregate class and put the method there instead. That though is a decision you would only want to make later when your domain starts getting more complicated.

Comment: First of all, you are clearly knowledgeable and a lot of the things you said makes me happy, because it means there are developers out there who care about quality of the code:) Indeed, most of what you said I've already learned (been a long time since I've posted this question). BUT! My question was - "Why is passing stateful objects to constructor a bad thing?" - and I'm sorry, I'm not sure you answered it.

Comment: Nothing says its wrong. In fact I doubt that there are any principles that even mention constructors. Constructors are only an implementation detail. That's why I widened the scope of my answer.